# use .net core sdk in MSBuild project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, sdk

I have a PCL-project with different functions and classes for each platform. I want to implement .net core support now. But I cant use controls like `UserControl` because the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` SDK isn't referenced. The .net framework is easy to implement because I only have to reference each assembly... But in .net core, I can't reference the assembly...

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;xamarin.ios10;xamarin.mac20;xamarin.tvos10;monoandroid10.0;tizen40</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">uap10.0.17763;net472;netcoreapp3.1;$(TargetFrameworks)</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4')) And '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    ...
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcoreapp3')) And '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    ...
    <SDKReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

That's my executable app, referencing the PCL-project above;

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference ...... />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I already tried this to reference the SDK but its not working.

```
 <SDKReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop" />
```

[image]

Comment: I have a solution and you can check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to implement .net core support now. But I cant use controls
> like UserControl because the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK
> isn't referenced. The .net framework is easy to implement because I
> only have to reference each assembly... But in .net core, I can't
> reference the assembly..

After doing a deep research, I found that `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` cannot be used by **SDKReference**.

As a suggestion, you could create a custom targets file and then import it into your **PCL-project** to use the Net Core SDK.

**1)** create a file called `custom.targets` in your **PCL** project folder.

**2)** Then add these in `custom.targets`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

    <PropertyGroup>         
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**3)** import this in `xxx.csproj` file of **PCL-Project**.

```
<Import  Project="$(ProjectDir)custom.targets" Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcoreapp3')) And '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' "/>
```

**4)** Then restart your project. Although there are some warnings that reminds you that some sdks are repeatedly quoted, you can ignore them and it will not have any impact on your project.

You can check this, which works well in my side.

[image]